# MVC 5 Hide Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form created in MVC 5.  There is a text box below:

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client_PID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">

          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_PID,   new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }  } )
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client_PID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

      </div>
</div>
```

I want to make this for conditionally invisible with a default value, else to be filled in by the customer.

What is the best way to accomplish this.  I have been able to make the text box invisible conditionally, but then my form fails,
 if (ModelState.IsValid) is not valid...how do I pass a default value into this?

Comment: What default value do you want?  This could potentially be setup in the controller actionresult method.  Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HiddenFor` when you want it to be hidden and in other case you can generate text box, for example:

```
@if(ShouldBeVisible)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_PID,   new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }  } )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client_PID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
else
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Client_PID,1)
}
```

Now on the base of `bool` we are creating hidden field and setting it's default value otherwise it will generate text box and user would need to fill in value.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a input checkbox and a jQuery function to control this display/hide effect and its target default value.

```
<label for="hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hidden" class="display-hidden" data-target=".hidden" />
    Show Client ID?
</label>

<div class="form-group hidden">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client_PID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_PID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client_PID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the jQuery function:

```
$(".display-hidden").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("data-target");
    if($(this).is(':checked'){
        $(target).fadeIn(320);
    } else {
        $(target).fadeOut(320);
        $(target).val(//your default value);
    }
});
```

Comment: The plus of using a jQuery function is that you can use it again in a later occasion.

Comment: You should put the `.hidden` on the whole `.form-group` as it will be a much nicer user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it...I figured it out before I looked at your awesome answers...thank you for helping!!

@if (true)
        {
        put in the filed
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_PID, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "display:none" } })
        }

Perhaps this is not best practice?